# Finding frequency of each element in an array

Tags: java

I have made a java program where  i have to print the frequency of each element in the array only once without using Collections.
Below is the Code which i implemented it.How to stop counting the element which i counted just now 
for example 4 4.4 has occurred 2 times the next 4 hence should not be counted.

```
static void countdigit(int x[])
 {
   for(int pass=x.length;pass>=0;pass--)
     {
       for(int i=0;i<pass-1;i++)
        {
          if(x[i]<x[i+1])
            {
                int temp=x[i];
                x[i]=x[i+1];
                x[i+1]=temp;
            }
        }
     }

   int count=0;
   int p[]=new int[x.length];
   for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++)
     { System.out.print(x[i]);     @Edit 1
       System.out.print(" ");
     }
    for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++)
     { for(int j=0;j<x.length;j++)
       {
        if(x[i]==x[j])
        {            
          count++;
        }
       }
         System.out.println();
         System.out.println(count);

         count=0;
     }
  } 
  public static void main(String s[])
 {
  countdigit(new int[] {1,4,4,2,3,4,3,3});   
 }
}

OutPutShown
4 4 4 3 3 3 2 1 
3

3

3

3

3

3

1

1
```

i want output as

```
  4 3, 

  3,3

  2,1

  1,1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a couple of changes.

First, do a println after outputting the original digits, to separate them from the first count.

Second, you are printing the count for element the same number of times as it appears. After printing the count the first time you see a value you should skip, without counting and printing, until you come to a different value.

Comment: How to check whether the first element is printed or not?

Answer (score 3):

You can use standard java methods:

```
void countdigit(Integer[] x) {
    List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(x);
    for(int item : x) {
        int frequency = Collections.frequency(ints, item);
        System.out.println(frequency);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For Java's sake, it's 2015 today. Even 10 years ago it would be something like this:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class test {

    static void countdigit(int x[]) {
        HashMap<Integer,Integer>digits=new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
        for (int i : x){
            if (digits.containsKey(i)){
                digits.put(i, digits.get(i)+1);
            } else {
                digits.put(i, 1);
            }
        }
        for (int key:digits.keySet()){
            System.out.println(key+"x"+digits.get(key));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String s[]) {
        countdigit(new int[] { 1, 4, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3 });
    }
}
```

With Java 8, streams and lambdas it would be couple lines of code which I'm shy to present as the answer for this question...

Comment: I favor this solution. Streams and lambdas have their place but lack the clarity of an iterative solution.

Comment: Without using these Apis i have to write this program.Use your logic and not the apis logic.

Comment: @javaCoderMakeSimple It's not API it's language right now. I like Assembler with 21 commands and 7 registers. I really do. It's pure beauty. But I wouldn't put tag Java on my Assembler code.

Comment: @Alex How to write ur for each loop for (int key:digits.keySet()) in reverse order that is if i want to print the elements in decreasing order of their frequency.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use the new java 8 stream api :

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Integer tab[] = {12,45,45,12,1,36,78,12,45,12,45,89,36,45,14,78,12,45};
        HashMap<Integer,Integer> h = Stream.of(tab).collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(e->e,
                HashMap<Integer,Integer>::new,
                Collectors.summingInt(e->1)
                ));
        System.out.println(h);
    }
}
```

Comment: Without using these Apis i have to write this program.Use your logic and not the apis logic. –